# Attribute extraction from GeoJSON to symbolize - OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, geojson

Loading polygons from geoserver via OpenLayers using GeoJSON.  My plan is to symbolize using attributes in the GeoJSON.  I am struggling to access the attributes.  Any insight appreciated:

The geometries are drawing, so I know that the GeoJSON is being passed from the backend to the client.

Wrapped in an init() function and called on page load:

```
        map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', options);

        var protocol = new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({ 
        url: "http://osgeostack:8080/geoserver/fjtests/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=fjtests:counties", 
        featureNS: "fj_tests", 
        featureType: "counties", 
        outputFormat: 'json', 
        readFormat: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON() 
        }); 


        layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("GML", {
            isBaseLayer: true,
            //styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap(style),
            protocol: protocol,
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()]
        });
            alert(layer.attributes) \\undefined
            alert(layer.features.length) \\ 0
            map.addLayer(layer)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You layer.attributes is undefined because attributes are on features (this means that among other things a features in a layer may have different attributes).

To style your map the simplest way would be to create a [Style](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Style-js.html) for your layer which contains [OpenLayers Rules](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Rule-js.html). Take a look at the [OpenLayers Rule Based Style](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/examples/style-rules.html) for a complete example, but I've written a simple one below that you could use for a polygon set (I'm assuming that's what "counties" will be). Note that the first argument of a Style is the default [Symbolizer](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Symbolizer/Polygon-js.html) object.

```js
var style = new OpenLayers.Style(
    {
        strokeColor: '#000000', //hex colour, in this case black
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        strokeWidth: 1,
        strokeLinecap: "butt", //or "round" or "square"
        fillColor: "#ffffff",
        fillOpacity: 0.3
    },
    // sample rule
    {
        rules: [
            new OpenLayers.Rule({
                filter: new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
                    type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
                    property: "name", // geojson property
                    value: "Unknown" //property value
                }),
                symbolizer: { //Colour Unknown counties red
                    strokeColor: '#ff0000',
                    strokeOpacity: 1,
                    strokeWidth: 1,
                    strokeLinecap: "butt",
                    fillColor: "#ff0000",
                    fillOpacity: 1,
                    label: "${name}" //Label based on name property
                }
            })
        ]
    }
);
```